# Port 80 forwarding - no css or images

Tags: port, forwarding

ive got a bit of a problem at the minute. I have an xampp web server set up on my home computer and ive configured my router to forward port 80 requests to it. (im using dyndns to resolve my dynamic ip) However, although it retrieves the expected information from the server, it is missing all CSS and images. Does anybody know the answer or even better point me to towards any resources that would explain the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your Apache access/error logs?

Comment: Who on earth voted to close this as "Blatantly Offensive"???

Answer (score 2):

I would look at your html and check that you're using valid paths to the images and css. If you're using fully qualified URL's with a local host name it wont work through your router.